# couldn't rosrun new executable after changing the source code

Tags: catkin-make, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to sending head move command to pr2 robot, and in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have `add_executable(point_head src/point_head.cpp)`, after `catkin_make`, I can use `rosrun simple_head point_head` to move the head of pr2.

Then I changed the head position in `point_head.cpp` and `catkin_make` again. But when I  `rosrun simple_head point_head` again, the head of pr2 stills goes to the position unchanged. While when I manually run `point_head` in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/simple_head/`, it goes to the new position correctly.

Is there anyone know why I couldn't run the new changed executable? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203321/couldn%27t-rosrun-new-executable-after-changing-the-source-code/) by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you have multiple copies of `point_head` on your systems and you're running one that is different than the one you are building.

You need to make sure you source the `setup.bash` file which is generated by `catkin_make` (which should be at `~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` based on your question) before trying to use `rosrun simple_head point_head`. You probably have `simple_head` installed somewhere else either in an `~/catkin_ws/install` folder or you've installed it from `.deb`'s perhaps. You can look at your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` to see what folders `simple_head` is being searched for in to try and debug which one it is finding.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on 2015-02-17**:
I've checked the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `~/catkin_ws/src` is in it. And when I `roscd simple_head`, it goes to the correct package. while I don't have a `~/catkin_ws/install` folder....

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-17**:
`~/catkin_ws/install` was just a guess, I think it is more likely that `/opt/ros/indigo` or something like that is on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. You can also just try to locate all instances of `simple_head` to track down which one might be getting executed.

**Comment by [guodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4544/guodi/) on 2015-02-17**:
That works. There is a copy of it in another package ... Thank you!